# What's the Next number in series #3?

Tags: number-sequence

Find out the next number in following **Simple** series,

> 15, 55, 120, 210, 325, ?, ?

Note: Question has many solutions.

Comment: It's 5 times 3,11,24,42,65,...

Comment: explain more! what's this series 3,11,24,42,65....

Comment: A lot of answers, and not the simple one: it's the sequence containing every 5th triangle number.

Comment: You shouldn't add a solution to your question. There's a button at the bottom to "answer your own question" if this is what you want to do.

Comment: [OEIS A144312](https://oeis.org/A144312)

Comment: @Phylogenesis I wrote my answer after staying up until 7am just as I crawled into bed. I was excited and confused that my brain could process an answer xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is:

> 465

Because:

> You add 5 to the factor of 5 being added. Between first two you add $5 \times 8$, next one you add $5 \times 13$, then $5 \times 18$, then $5 \times 23$, so next you add $5 \times 28$, ending with $5 \times 93 = 465$.

Answer (score 3):

It's

> $$465$$

Because:

> $$t_n=\frac{5}2n(n+5)$$

Comment: Are you sure???

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati yes.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati In which way my answer is different or wrong than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You start by (adding) 15, so you have 15. From then you keep adding the same number as before plus 25.

Therefore the sequence is:

> $$15,55,120,210,325,465,630$$

Comment: sorry , but i can't understand? please explain more..

Comment: You first add 15 (from 0), then 15+25=40, then 40+25=65, then 65+25=90, and so on.

Comment: your answer and logic both are Right!